# Will there be an automatic update function integrated in the final version of elementary OS 6?

Tags: updates

First of all, I love elementary OS. It's super easy to use, looks great and is fast. Some of my friends and family are using it after my recommendation as well and are quite pleased with it.
The only thing, I really miss, is an **AUTOMATIC UPDATE FUNCTION**, not only for security updates, but for all installed applications and the system as well. I would really love to install elementary OS 6 on my mothers computer, but unfortunately she is 75 and not able to do manually updates on her own, like a lot of others who are older. We can't expect technical understanding from the elderly generation.

Linux Mint has it implemented already and it is working great and stable according to a friend of mine. Of course he is using Timeshift to make system snapshots regularly.

**My question is, can we expect to have a system wide Auto Update function in elementary OS 6 in the near future?**

Best regards and thank you for your great work!
Shaka

Comment: It's funny how we condemn sexism and racism, but ageism is allowed. "We can't expect technical understanding from the elderly generation."
Better to say "We can't expect technical understanding from my mother".
What if someone said "We can't expect technical understanding from women". etc.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic updates would be cool! This feature doesn't appear to be planned for elementary OS 6, but it could be added in the future.

There is a [GitHub issue for automatic updates](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/288) and [another issue for automatic security updates](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/20). That said, this feature doesn't appear to be in development, and there's no mention of such a feature in [this elementary OS 6 update](https://blog.elementary.io/updates-for-july-2020/).

The good news is that there are bounties on both of those issues, and the elementary OS team does seem to be in favor of implementing automatic updates.